# Query DSL - joining tables

Tags: querydsl

Im new Query DSL . I have the below query and want to write using     QueryDSL.Looking forward for help on this.

```
  select * from table1 l 
  join table2 lc 
  on l.ColumnA = lc.ColumnD
  where l.name = 'ABC'
  and lc.role='XYZ'
  and l.status ='A'.
```

l.ColumnA = lc.ColumnD - These do not have relation mapping.

Not sure how to write the on condition.

```
    query.from(table1).join(table2).on(table1.ColumnA.eq       (**table2.ColumnB**)).where(table1.name.eq("ABC").and(table2.Role.eq("XYZ")));
```

I get an error as --The method eq(String) in the type SimpleExpression is not applicable for the arguments

Comment: What are the types of ColumnA and ColumnB?

Comment: In SQL code you use ColumnD and in Java code you use ColumnB.